# Unable to deploy using icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee

Tags: dockerhub, ibm-cloud-private

i run the following command to deploy a new cluster:

docker run --net=host -t -e LICENSE=accept -v "$(pwd)":/installer/cluster ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee install

and i get this response:

Unable to find image 'ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee not found.
See 'docker run --help'.

This happened about a couple of weeks ago, and when i did nothing other than wait a few days and tried again, the command worked.  It is as if the tag, 2.1.0.2-ee is not accessible.  indeed, when i go to docker hub, i don't see that tag listed.  But then i'm a newbie with docker hub so I'm not sure if i'm interpreting this correctly.

is it me, or is ee not available to all? i could do a docker pull with ce, no problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't you! ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee points to the paid-for version of IBM Cloud Private and is not distributed through DockerHub. We distribute our community edition, ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ce, (which is free to use) via DockerHub, which is why you are not having any issues with ce.

The only difference you will find between Community Edition and Enterprise Edition is that multi-master deployments and production are not enabled in Community Edition.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone on slack and stack overflow.

My mistake was that the snapshot that i took just prior to deploying the cluster successfully was not what i thought.
i think i must have checkpointed prior to loading ee into docker rather than just before running icp-inception.
It makes sense that icp ee is not publicly downloadable.